# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Button

Tags: python, windows, kivy

Can anyone tell me what this means

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Button
```

I am trying to make a kivy app that opens a file browser and save a file from a link. I can get it to work successfully without the file browser being implemented, but when I add a file browser using plyer/ilechooser I cannot seem to get the button press to save the file. For example:

1. I paste the link in a text box.
2. press the file browser button
3. file browser opens I choose a location to save the file
4. Then I click save.
5. I am presented with that error upon clicking the download button i have created

(I also believe the error occurs when I am trying to get the location from one function to another and the second function requires a path to save the file.)

I think I a getting this error because when I choose the location, it is not giving me a raw string however i could be wrong.
if you need the code let me know.

EDIT: Here is the code I am working on. Ignore any unnecessary imports this code is a work in progress.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from plyer import filechooser
from pytube import YouTube
import os

class SayHello(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        self.window.size_hint = (0.6, 0.7)
        self.window.pos_hint = {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        self.window.add_widget(Image(source="logo.png"))

        #Label

        self.videolink = Label(text = "What is the link of your Youtube video?" ,
                               font_size =18

                               )
        self.window.add_widget(self.videolink)
        self.user = TextInput(multiline = False,
                              padding_y = (20,20),
                              size_hint = (1, 0.5)
                              )
        self.window.add_widget(self.user)

        self.loc = Label(text = "what is the location where you want this file saved? ",
                         font_size =18
                         )
        self.window.add_widget(self.loc)
        #self.lc = TextInput(multiline = False,
        #                    padding_y = (20,20),
        #                    size_hint = (1, 0.5))
        #self.window.add_widget(self.lc)
        self.buttonone = Button(text = "Choose where to save",
                                size_hint = (1, 0.5),
                                bold =True
                                )
        self.buttonone.bind(on_press=self.filebrowser)
        self.window.add_widget(self.buttonone)
        #Button

        self.button = Button(text = " Download Video",
                             size_hint = (1, 0.5),
                             bold = True,
                             background_color = '#32FFD1'
                             )
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)

        return self.window
    
    def filebrowser(self, instance):
        path = filechooser.save_file(title="Choose where to Save", 
                             filters=[( "*.mp4")])
        return path
    def callback(self, path):
        self.videolink.text = "Video Downloading Please Wait... "
        t = YouTube(self.user.text)
        l = path
        highresvid = t.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        highresvid.download(output_path = l)


SayHello().run()
```

Comment: How do you expect someone to debug your problem without giving the code? Post the relevant code

Comment: I added the code in an edit. Its a little messy, as I am trying to learn how to use kivy.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me what this means `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Button`

A [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)  indicates that "an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type." You passed a Button (most likely a [`kivy.uix.button.Button`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html)) as an argument to a function that expected a path instead. The error also tell you what types it can accept: `str`, `bytes`, or an `os.PathLike` object (e.g. [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html))